# complexity of printing all possible paths on a graph

Tags: graph, complexity-theory

In an undirected, unweighted graph, and I'm trying to print (store in file) all possible connecting paths between given 2 vertices on the graph, not including cycles.

when you consider a complete graph this problem is a NP-complete. because there are `"(V-2)!"` different paths between 2 vertices.

However,seems it is possible to do it with one of graph traversal (DFS-BFS) algorithm with time complexity of `O(|V|+|E|)` which is pretty polynomial.

I got confuse about solving a NP-Complete problem in polynomial time?
any idea about what is missing here ?

Comment: Your O(|V|+|E|) claim is wrong (I'm guessing you misinterpreted something): make an n+1 by n+1 grid graph and ask for the number of paths from the top-left vertex to the bottom-right one.  Clearly you can get there by moving down n rows and right n columns, and you can intermingle these moves in any order, so there are `(2n choose n)` different paths between them that don't even involve any doubling back.

Comment: @ j_ random_hacker I think I can print all possible paths by visiting all nodes and all edges once while recording current path

Comment: But how many paths will there be?  E.g. on my example graph?

Comment: so O(|V|+|E|) is valid for only one path ? complexity has to be multiply by number of  paths ?  if it is a complete graph , is it going to be v!*O(|V|+|E|) ?

Comment: I don't know where you got "O(|V|+|E|)" from, but obviously printing a single path is O(|V|+|E|).  And if the problem is "Print all possible paths on a graph" then of course you need to have a factor in there for the number of paths!

Comment: that was pretty clear .thanx

Answer (score 1):

If you want all possible paths, and the graph has V vertices, and E edges, then the number of paths will be dependent upon the number of connects.  Consider a fully connected graph, where every point connects to every other point.  Then there are `(v-2)!` possible paths, right?  Well `(v-2)! > V+E` (much greater).

Comment: I have misses that O(|V|+|E|) is complexity of checking existence of a single path.